# Can I pipe output from a started process?

Tags: pipe, background-process

Say I've started `program` and it continues writing some output to stdout.  Is there some way to add a pipe so that I can, for example, count the number of lines it has produced with `wc -l`?

Comment: It may be possible, but how that would be done is probably dependent on what Unix you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Linux. Say there's a script `s`:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
echo my pid: "$$"
while true; do
    echo "$i"; ((i++)); sleep 1; 
done
```

Run it:

```
$ ./s
my pid: 8815
0
1
2
```

And so it goes... Now you need `gdb` to attach to the process.

```
gdb -p 8815
```

Now you're in `gdb`. Here do this:

```
p close(1)
```

This has closed the STDOUT file descriptor. Now open a new one:

```
p creat("/tmp/8815.out", 0600)
```

In another terminal you can already set the reading process:

```
tail -f /tmp/8815.out
```

Nothing's coming yet, as you need to detach from `gdb` in the other terminal. Either <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or:

```
q
Quit anyway? (y or n)
```

Confirm with `y` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And now you should see (where the `tail` is running) something like this:

```
173
174
175
```

If you prefer to use an already existing file or pipe, do this in `gdb`:

```
p open("/path/to/your/output", 1)
```

This illustrates redirecting STDOUT. It's similar with STDERR, only it has number 2.

---

I used these two answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/6631810
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834605/6631810

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` when you start the program.  If you're using bash, you can do:

```
program > >(tee -a log.txt)
```

That will redirect the stdout of `program` to a process substitution running `tee`.  That essentially writes a copy of the stdout of `program` to `log.txt`.  `tee` will continue to send the stdout to wherever it was going before, probably the terminal depending on how `program` works.

Comment: This is useful but can i do this if I've already started `program`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be possible with `strace`.  Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin